# Running two commands in same variable in Bash CGI

Tags: linux, bash, get, cgi

In my Bash CGI script, I take a command passed as GET parameter and execute it. This could be:

```
CMD='ls -al'
$CMD
```

Which works fine and produces expected output. But if I try to pass two commands with

```
CMD='ls -al; echo hello'
$CMD
```

or

```
CMD='ls -al && echo hello'
$CMD
```

neither command gets executed.

**How can I run multiple commands from the same line/variable in my bash CGI?**

Comment: [Don't put commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). It will very quickly stop working as your commands get more complicated. As you have just seen for example.

Comment: @EtanReisner What would you suggest for my scenario then? I have to get commands from a GET variable, clean the URL encoding, and execute it.

Comment: You have to create a remote shell which executes arbitrary commands passed as `GET` parameters? That is pretty much **horrendously** unsafe *even if* you have tried to sanitize the input.

Comment: @EtanReisner It's part of an assignement and it being horrendously unsafe is part of the point. Regardless, I'm nearly there, except mine only works with one command at a time, need to find a way to pass multiple commands as **one** string (with a command seperator) run those in a shell.

Comment: Then you probably just need to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute variables as bash code using `bash`:

```
# UNSAFE, DO NOT USE
cmd='ls -al; echo hello'
bash -c "$cmd"
```

Alternatively, depending on the context you want to run it in, you can use `eval "$cmd"` to run it as if it was a line in your own script, rather than a separate piece of shell code to execute:

```
# UNSAFE, DO NOT USE
cmd='ls -al; echo hello'
eval "$cmd"
```

Both of these methods have serious implications for security and correctness, so I felt I had to add warnings to prevent them from being copied out of context.

For your remote shell or root kit specifically meant to run insecure user input, you can ignore the warnings.

Comment: If you are writing your own utility script this is as much unsafe as script itself. This would be unsafe if used within utility you plan to distribute for use by wider audience, and what more important, string passed to eval is dynamicaly built and consiting information coming from input influcenced by user.

Security implications cannot be defined until you evaluate risks and potential impact. Microscopic risk and microscopic impact equals no security implication.